# Multisite solution restrict access to component

Tags: components

Our client has a multiwebsites solution and I have to restrict a component to be accessible only into one of the websites. Is there something built into Sitecore, or should I do it programmatically?

Thank you, M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can make use of Sitecore security model.

1. You can create custom roles per site like "Site1 Role", "Site2 Role" etc.
2. Add other roles and users to these roles as required.
3. In the Security Access editor, configure the components such that only the corresponding Roles you created above, are allowed to access them

Comment: Adding images to highlight the process you are describing can go a long way towards improving the quality of this answer.